# Can we change content of powerbi report using powerbi rest

Tags: java, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

1. Can we change content of Power BI report using Power BI REST API, say in
   some report 'Col A' has been used and I want to change it to 'Col
   B'. 'Col A' and 'Col B' are in same dataset and same table.
2. In updatereportcontent API, what can be the possible value of
   sourcetypeenum apart from 'ExistingReport'?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/updatereportcontent#sourcetypeenum

I am using Power BI native application to do this task.

Answer (score 1):

First about question #2 - as you can see in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/updatereportcontent#sourcetypeenum) you gave, `ExistingReport` is the only possible value.

[image]

About your first question - you can't do this directly using the API. However, you can use a text value parameter (let's name it `ColName`) to hold the name of the column you want to select. Modify the M query for fetching the data from the database by changing it from:

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database(ServerName, DatabaseName, [Query="select Col1, Col2, ColA from Sales.Orders"])
in
    Source
```

to:

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database(ServerName, DatabaseName, [Query="select Col1, Col2, " & ColName & " as ColA from Sales.Orders"])
in
    Source
```

Then use [Update Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/updateparameters) or [Update Parameters In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/updateparametersingroup) API to change the value of `ColName` parameter (to let's say `ColB`). If this is imported dataset, you must refresh it using [Refresh Dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/refreshdataset) or [Refresh Dataset In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/refreshdatasetingroup) after that.

Comment: Thanks @Andrey, I get it we can update dataset and refresh data. but Update Parameter api is for updating dataset, not to update/modify report. Am i not correct ?

Comment: Kind of. Yes, it does not update the report itself. It changes parameter values. Parameters are not exactly part of the dataset, because they can exists even without a dataset, but changing their values is part of the datasets related API. In practice, you will not change the report, but will change the underlying query, and indirectly you will change the column shown in the report.